# How to debug my website on smartphones

Tags: css, debugging, tablet, smartphone

What are the best ways for debugging website on Smartphones and Tablets ?

I only need to test CSS.
At the moment, my website is not responsive.

I'm looking for two things:
 - a way to test my web site on different screen sizes
 - a way to inspect elements, like you can do in Chrome and Firefox.

[image]

OS: win 8.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For Android:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

or

http://html5-mobile.de/blog/android-remote-web-debugging-chrome (only in german)

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!! there is a simple way to do that with iphone or ios devices on windows?